# Npgsql failing on CommandBuilder DeriveParameters

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

In attempting to use the following code, I receive this error:

> Message: Invalid parameter type: 277447
>   Source: Npgsql

The program bombs on execution of:

> NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

```
   NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "g_savedx";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
                    cmd.Parameters["_cpatient"].Value = cpatient;
                    cmd.Parameters["o"].Value = olddx;
                    cmd.Parameters["n"].Value = newdx;
                    var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                }
```

The PostgreSQL 9.1 stored procedure is defined as:

> FUNCTION g_savedx(_cpatient text, o view_dx, n view_dx)
>     RETURNS void

where view_dx are simple tables in the PostgreSQL database.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newbies like myself, the above usage of DeriveParameters is correct--as is the error message from Npgsql. The basic problem is that the interface to the PostgreSQL stored function can only use DbTypes specified by the NpgsqlDbType enumeration. The composite type "Object" or "View_dx" does not exist in NpgsqlDbType (at this time) so DerviveParameters fails.

My solution was to serialize the object into one or more of the enumerations allowed by NpgsqlDbType and change the stored procedure interface accordingly.